# Solving $2\sin(\theta + 17) = \frac {\cos (\theta +8)}{\cos (\theta + 17)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

For $0<\theta<360$

$$2\sin(\theta + 17) = \dfrac {\cos (\theta +8)}{\cos (\theta + 17)}$$

$$\Longrightarrow \sin(2\theta + 34)= \sin (82-\theta)$$

since sine is an odd function

$$2\theta + 34 = 82-\theta + 360n$$

This gives $ \theta = 16, 136, 256$

But in the solution paper I can also see $64$. 
Why is it missing from the above method?

I can get $64$ (due to $\cos$)when I use
$$ \sin(\alpha) - \sin(\beta) = 2\sin\left(\dfrac {\alpha - \beta} 2\right)\cos\left(\dfrac {\alpha + \beta} 2\right)$$

But the first method I use should still work no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that $\sin(2\theta + 34)= \sin (82-\theta)$ **if** $2\theta + 34 = 82-\theta + 360n$.

It is not true that $\sin(2\theta + 34)= \sin (82-\theta)$ **only if** $2\theta + 34 = 82-\theta + 360n$.

Remember that $\sin(180^\circ-\alpha) = \sin\alpha$.  Thus if $\sin(2\theta+34^\circ) = \sin(82^\circ-\theta+n360^\circ)$ then
$$
\sin(2\theta+34^\circ) = \sin(180^\circ-\Big(82^\circ-\theta+n360^\circ\Big))
$$
and you'll get additional solutions.

Comment: Aha! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

The general solution to the equation:

> $$\sin(x)=\sin(\alpha)$$

is actually given by the following:

$$x=n\pi+(-1)^n\alpha~\forall~n\in\Bbb Z$$

(I'm assuming in radians).

Answer (score 2):

You also need to use the fact that $\sin x = \sin (180 - x)$.

Comment: Sorry, my intention was just to provide a hint.